# Time difference between two values based on other column value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have some problems with counting a time passed between records in SQL.
Or as in my case, how long the item was not active.

Sample of data:

```
Item  Not_Active Active Created
A     0          1      2017-01-01 10:03:15 
A     1          0      2017-01-01 12:05:55
A     0          1      2017-01-01 13:05:55
A     1          0      2017-02-03 12:05:55
A     0          1      2017-02-05 13:05:55
B     1          0      2017-01-10 04:05:20 
B     0          1      2017-01-10 07:05:20
```

So the main goal is to **sum all time between deactivation and activation for each item**. Answer should be in seconds. What kind of query should I use?

**Challenge two**: to count not active time between certain dates. For example, for item A just between 2017-02-01 and 2017-02-28.

**Challenge three**: to count how much not active time was during the night, lets say between 0 am till 5 am.

I have no idea where should I start. Any suggestions?

Comment: visual results can also be helpful alongside your schema and also if you can flag the correct database

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: T-SQL use DATEDIFF with logic sending in dates based on your arbitrary business logic.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using Microsoft SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a little sample how you can made this.

```
    create table #table (item char, not_active int, active int, created datetime)

    insert into #table values('A', 0, 1, '2017-01-01 10:03:15') 
    insert into #table values('A', 1, 0, '2017-01-01 12:05:55') 
    insert into #table values('A', 0, 1, '2017-01-01 13:05:55') 
    insert into #table values('A', 1, 0, '2017-02-03 12:05:55') 
    insert into #table values('A', 0, 1, '2017-02-05 13:05:55') 
    insert into #table values('B', 1, 0, '2017-01-10 04:05:20') 
    insert into #table values('B', 0, 1, '2017-01-10 07:05:20') 

    declare @very_hard table (item char, 
                          not_active int, 
                          active int, 
                          created datetime,
                          before datetime, 
                          afters datetime,
                          days_diff_stoped int,
                          hourstoped int )

declare very_hard_challenge cursor Local
for

select 
item,
active,
not_active,
created,
LAG(created,1,0)over(partition by item order by created) as before,
LEAD(created,1,0)over(partition by item order by created) as afters,
datediff(day,LAG(created,1,0)over(partition by item order by created),created) as days_diff_stoped
from #table
--where item = 'B'
order by created asc

declare @item char, 
        @not_active int, 
        @active int, 
        @created datetime,
        @days_diff_stoped int,
        @before datetime, 
        @afters datetime

open very_hard_challenge

fetch next from very_hard_challenge into @item, @not_active, @active, @created, @before, @afters, @days_diff_stoped

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    begin 
        declare @datebegin datetime = @before
        declare @hourstoped int = 0
        if @datebegin != '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
        begin
            while @datebegin < convert(datetime,@created)
                begin 
                        if datepart(hour,@datebegin) in(0,1,2,3,4,5)
                            begin
                                set @hourstoped = @hourstoped+1
                            end 

                            set @datebegin = DATEADD(hour,1,@datebegin)
                end
        end

        insert into @very_hard values (@item, @not_active, @active, @created, @before, @afters, @days_diff_stoped, @hourstoped)

        fetch next from very_hard_challenge into @item, @not_active, @active, @created, @before, @afters, @days_diff_stoped
    end

close very_hard_challenge
deallocate very_hard_challenge

select * from @very_hard
```

This code has simple, but you can make better. Anyone question about this code please tell me and I will do make a possible for answer.

Comment: If this answer help you, please, accept by clicking the checkmark. This answer can be help other people. ;)

Comment: Sure! :) Igor, maybe you can also help me with the last challenge - how to count just a night time periods? :/

Comment: Look that brand new code, I believe I fulfilled the challenge.

Comment: Haha. Thank you, Igor. I will run a new code and will try to understand :)